# Is there any way to see the dataset and its content in Visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, debuggervisualizer

In Visual studio we have option to see the dataset using Dataset Visualizer as below image.

[image: dataset visualizer]

But in VS code, do we have anything like this? Any plug-in I can install to get this in VS code?

Currently in VS code I am getting as like this below image. Please help.

[image: VS code]

Answer (score 0):

Although C# support is not great yet, but the [Debug Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hediet.debug-visualizer) extension for VS Code might be exactly thing you are looking for.

There is no proper table visualizer yet and you would need to return JSON in your C# code, [but feel free to contribute](https://github.com/hediet/vscode-debug-visualizer) or to get in contact and share ideas!